# Small edits should be allowed

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, edits

I get why small edits are discouraged, but there should be an "it's ok; I'm helping, really!" checkbox, or something.

Example: I just tried to edit an otherwise great answer that contained a typo:

```
pit <some git command> # some explanation.
```

to read

```
git <some git command> # some explanation.
```

("pit" => "git" typo), but was told I had to change at least 6 chars for my edit to stick.

Given that this was an actual command-line command with a typo (could've been worse: `-w` wrong `-b` bash `-f` flag, or something more destructive), it seems weird that I had to go find a couple of other words to alter that didn't really improve the answer any, just to add my fix.

**"Edit Boldly!"**  :)

Comment: Yeah, check the revision history.  At 2k+, there is no restriction on a minimum edit.

Comment: @pnuts I don't see the reason to clog up the comments with things like that. Just go ahead and fix typos, if it's really just a typo. Logic errors, then sure - leave a comment. But not to change `pit` -> `git`

Comment: I had to be logged in, right?  Else I couldn't have edited at all, no?

Comment: @Olie Logged out users or those with no account can still suggest edits- The edit just has to be at least 6 characters in length and will have to get reviewed. Said edit is attributed to the Community user.

Comment: You had to have been logged out, I just tested it and can submit an edit with only one char changed.

Comment: Tiny: I'll take your word for it.  Seems a logical explanation.  Just odd that I could edit at all, then.  I wonder if it's a rep thing, and "any size" kicks in at 15k?  #shrug; whatever.  :)

Comment: +1 - I hate this!  Please this along with the regex's telling me not to start a comment with +1 need to be removed ASAP>

Comment: They can put in filler words like html tags or the no space character. However, IMHO giving rep for such small edits (though not in this case) would then mean more people making such edits and filling up the edit queue.

Comment: @BhargavRao does fixing typos count for nothing? Many times I've wanted to improve otherwise excellent answers.

Comment: how about, **don't** give rep points for edits, just for answers. And, don't allow just *anyone* to approve an edit, only the OP.

Comment: @johnywhy That would cause a huge drop in site quality. No thanks

Comment: @TylerH, not allowing legitimate edits reduces site quality. Also, how do you know how "huge" is the importance of points for edits?

Comment: @johnywhy reducing the number of people able to approve edits to the OP only would result in vastly more unapproved edits than continuing to require substantial edits from sub-2k users. So comparatively, implementing your suggestion would be a step backward.

Comment: I didn't know reputed ones can make edits of any length! I really want to format the code in this (https://stackoverflow.com/q/29738754/4062881) SO question properly..!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Suggested** edits have a minimum length, which is 6 characters on Stack Overflow. Note that there is no rep requirement to suggest edits. In fact, even anonymous users can suggest edits!

However, if you have [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), this doesn't apply, and you can make edits of any length.

Comment: But if you don't have full edit privileges and you don't want to make 6 edits...is his question.

Comment: This is not a satisfying answer. The vast majority of users don't have the required rep to suggest 1-character edits.

Comment: Actually, my original question may have been caused by a misunderstanding, where I thought I was logged-in but wasn't.  So what I thought was an edit may have been a (logged out) suggested edit.  This is a pretty decent answer, though it seems suggested-edits should also be allowed for small #s of characters (typos, punctuation, etc.)

Comment: I didn't know reputed ones can make edits of any length! I really want to format the code in this (stackoverflow.com/q/29738754/4062881) SO question properly..!

Comment: just came around this -- someone posted a broken link, I found the fix (it was only 1 character) and tried editing but couldn't!

Answer (score -6):

A version with misprint

```
    pit <some git command> # some explanation.
```

can be fixed via editing one char

```
    git <some git command> # some explanation.
```

or much more (enough to pass autovalidation):

```
<pre><code>git <some git command> # some explanation.</code></pre>
```

Comment: Yes, that "works". Still, there's probably something more constructive to do on that post than moving from markdown to html...

Comment: @Deduplicator, if there are somthing to edit, yep. But it can be that the other content is nice. And such edit doesn't introduce additional work to reviewers - they shouldn't remove [unnessesary text](/a/306878/4928642).

Comment: Oh please oh please don't introduce *bad* formatting to get around the minimum edit feature. Then people will just have to go around fixing what you've "fixed". If you repeatedly do this, I will flag a moderator to see about having your edit privileges temporarily suspended. Honestly, 6 characters isn't that much. You don't have to work around it in stupid ways. Any decent answer that is worth editing will have words, and there'll likely be typos and more information you can add to make it *better*.

Comment: @CodyGray, no, I don't. Anyway, why this formatting is bad?

Comment: @CodyGray " Any decent answer that is worth editing will have words, and there'll likely be typos and more information you can add to make it better." But what if there aren't? Why "likely"?

Answer (score -13):

I agree. If the purpose of this restriction to prevent willy-nilly trivial or incorrect edits by people who don't know what they're doing, that's unnecessary because the original poster retains the power to **reject the edits,** and **no one will see the edit unless the OP approves them.** Trust the OP!

update, i just found out anyone can approve edits, not just the OP. Is that a good idea?

in a recent answer, i found a CODE ERROR involving a single character. Because of this restriction i could not correct it. This is not a spelling error, or emoticon, or changing "its" to "it's". It's a CODE ERROR.

This makes no sense! Requiring 6 characters is completely arbitrary, and prevents legitimate edits.

This restriction prevented me from CORRECTING AND IMPROVING AN ANSWER-- as a result, this website is now displaying WRONG INFORMATION.

As the asker, i'm unable to mark that answer as the Solution!

Comment: Sadly, the OP can't reject edits if someone else approves it first. They can roll it back, but can't reject it. So there's still the potential to waste the time of both reviewers and OP for edits that don't do very much.

Comment: "don't do very much"? Or, are **incorrect?** Two very different things. Large edits can also be incorrect, min 6 chars won't protect us from that. Threads i participate in involve coding-- programming. In code, a single character can make the difference between code that works and code that doesn't.

Comment: *"no one will see the edit unless the OP approves them"* Except for the people in the review queue, of course.

Comment: Yes, and a single character can also make the difference between a perfectly good answer and a perfectly good answer that 3+ people have to review anyway. Even in cases where an important improvement can be made with a 1-character code, it behooves the editor to explain *why* the change is being made for the benefit of other readers. If you want to fix typos, earn 2K and edit with abandon.

Comment: ok, i don't know what the review queue is, but whatever it is, i assume the proposed edit is indicated as a "proposed edit", so people will know it's not the original post.

Comment: " it behooves the editor to explain why the change is being made for the benefit of other readers." -- i agree, we're not talking about explanations here.

Comment: "3+ people have to review" @Shog9, nobody HAS to do anything.

Comment: Indeed. No one has to edit either.

Comment: @Shog9, you said people "have" to review. That's false. Now you say nobody has to edit.  True, but nobody said they have to. What do you mean, nobody has to edit? How is that relevant?

Comment: If no one reviews the edit, the edit never gets made. That can be one post-author, or 3+ reviewers; commonly it'll be the latter because waiting for authors takes too long. So you're technically correct that "no one HAS to [review]", but this is only true if no one edits or we don't care if edits are ever applied. IOW, you are correct as long as we operate under the assumption that the system should be broken.

Comment: @Shog9 "3+ people have to review anyway" -- I'm still hearing conflicting info here. If the poster approves it, then nobody else has to review it, correct? And if a 1-character edit turns an invalid answer into a valid one, how is that not as substantially important to site quality to deserve the attention it takes to get it right? In a coding forum, i can not understand why people are minimizing the critical importance of single characters.

Answer (score -18):

This is one of the most annoying things I found about SO too. However, I have found a work-around. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31070025/2

Since you're still subject to approval you can just add a completely unrelated paragraph asking for it to be removed. That way you can suggest 1-character changes. I would love to avoid using this hack though!

Comment: That's really annoying, if you're the one who has to review the edit.

Comment: "Has to"? You can chose not to. Not as annoying as being prevented from making a simple 1-character fix that is the difference between making and breaking an answer, I bet.

Comment: Please do not do this. I generally Reject and Edit such changes, because otherwise it messes up the revision history with nonsense. Fillers should be invisible, always.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I would much rather 1-character suggested edits were allowed. But until sense prevails this is the only way I can help fix typos in otherwise excellent answers. You would rather answers stay broken to avoid messing up their revision history? That seems silly, IMO.

Comment: @StigBrautaset: No. I would rather **no one put rubbish into a post in an attempt to "fix" it**. If you have to add filler characters, make them invisible.

Comment: Oh right, adding invisible junk seems so much better than just making a 1-character change, or adding something that _documents itself_ to be unrelated so there's no confusion.

Comment: There is one rejection reason called: causes harm. I would use that to reject such edits. And as you said to mmking earlier I say to you: You can chose not to. Leaving a comment is a better option. Focus on getting to 2K so you get editor privileges

Comment: Leaving a comment is one option, true. It's often much more work explaining exactly what the fix should be than just doing the edit, though. And I think part of the problem is that I only find out that I can't save an edit _after I have actually made it_. If I couldn't edit at all, but encourage to "suggest edit" by adding a comment then I would be much more likely to do that.

Comment: @StigBrautaset: `<!-- filler -->` is self-documenting and invisible.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but `<!-- filler -->` is hardly self-documenting.  Why the hell is there filler here?!?!  Better would be `<!-- filler to meet the minimum edit-length requirement -->`, though even that's pretty lame, IMO.

Comment: @nathantuggy but any filler is IMO worse for both the person suggesting edits and the person reviewing such edits. Do we agree at least here? So the sensible solution seems to be allow 1-char suggested edits for everyone.

Comment: Bad way. Someone else needs to remove extra part.